# spring data - native Mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-data

Is it possible to create a native Mysql query with spring-data?

I have a mysql query I would  like to execute as is (since hibernate doesnt allow me to do it).

P.S The query return strings as output. (not multiple values)

Comment: Error log would be helpful to understand your problem further.

Answer (score 0):

with hibernate you can do it using native query:

```
getSession().getNamedQuery("distintaPrelievo")
            .setString("codiceLancio", codiceLancio)
            .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(PrelievoDTO.class))
            .list();
```